# Turn a shared folder into a network item always present

Tags: home-networking, file-sharing

I would like my network users to have a shared folder mapped without having them to do anything themselves. Is it possible to turn a shared folder into a network item like the list of PC's there is in the network view?

The boot script is an option but it's still an operation on the end user's machines. I would very much like a permanent solution that involves zero client-side operations.

We're mostly on w7 but Mac support would not hurt.

I don't mind investing in a small computer-like machine (raspberry pi or something) if absolutely required.

Comment: I'm thinking of a bin-like folder that anyone bringing his laptop would be able to access super-easily. My best option ATM would be to write down the UNC path somewhere obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't not have a server and expect no work to be done on the client side. This is why servers exist.

In your case, map the drives yourself - you would only need to do it once on each client machine. Or inform your network users how to do this themselves and award gold stars to those who succeed. Then the ones lagging behind will feel pressured to educate themselves, forging habits that will serve them well when something goes wrong and you are not there.

This really isn't a whole lot to ask of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would buy a Windows server, and set the server up as a domain controller. You can set every user on your domain to have the mapped drive with group policy.

Comment: It is an option that I cannot take since I'll have to put all the computers in the domain one by one. I'm looking more of an always-ready-no-user-setup solution